# R - Make different subsets of a big dataset

Tags: r, subset

I have a rather large dataset `test_data` with more than 30'000 observations and 20 variables.
I would like to make smaller subsets based on the number of the set, which is determined under `test_data$set`. The size of the subset will vary (as shown below).

For a small dataset, I would subset the rows as follows:

```
test_data <- data.frame(measurement=c(2,34,5,6,7,38,3,4,29,11,12,4,5,6,91,13,13,13,12))
test_data <- mutate(test_data,set=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4))

set1 <- subset(test_data, set == 1)
set2 <- subset(test_data, set == 2)
set3 <- subset(test_data, set == 3)
set4 <- subset(test_data, set == 4)
```

But since my data set is huge, I am looking for a way to make subsets without typing each subset command. 
Is anyone experienced with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be `split` to split into a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
lst <- split(test_data, test_data$set)
```

and then do the processing within the `list`.  It is recommended not to create lots of objects in the global environment. If we need to do any group by operations, then `group_by` from `dplyr` or `by` from `data.table` would be fast

Comment: Thank you for helping. So if I understand correctly, there is no way to do it in a one-line code (like the one you showed) with avoiding to get a list?

Comment: @Jael  It is better to keep it in a `list` rather than creating individual datasets.  But from the above `lst`, you can still get dataset objects ie. `list2env(setNames(lst, paste0("set", names(lst))), envir = .GlobalEnv)` but I wouldn't recommend to have that way

Comment: Okay, I see,  thank you very much :-)